# Information on the word 'scower'

Tags: verbs

I swear I've heard, and read the phrase before.

- "He scowered the land, far and wide".

I have used the word many times, but recently someone said to me that it isn't a word. There is

- ***scour*** (1) *clean or brighten the surface of (something) by rubbing it hard, typically with an abrasive or detergent.* [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/scour)]

But that wasn't the definition I was looking for. I finally found

- **scour** (2) *search and search for something or someone*.

This was obviously the sense I was looking for, but I wanted more information and [YourDictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/scower) gave me this:

- **scower** [obsolete] Alternative form of *scour* [verb]

I would like some more explanation on this. Please and thanks.

**Edit**: Why is the word '*obsolete*' as well as not being more widely used?

Comment: What explanation would you like that you have not already found?

Comment: Oxford Dictionaries gives 'subject [a place] to a thorough search' as a separate, second definition of _scour_. It's the alternative spelling that's obsolete, not the definition.

Comment: Hmm, thank you for clearing that up for me. I guess I just can't accept the fact that scour means both definitions. I just have it in my head that scower should be a different word, as well as having the definition you have described.

Comment: Note that Lexico attests that the etymologies of _scour (1)_ = clean or brighten the surface ... and _scour (2)_ = subject [a place] to a thorough search are different. These are indeed different words (homographs / homonyms) that have arisen by convergent evolutions, not different polysemes (senses) arising through broadening.

Comment: Now if you really want to make your head hurt, [look into](https://thebettereditor.wordpress.com/2014/03/29/riffle-vs-rifle-is-this-one-all-shot-to-pieces/) *rifle* vs *riffle* in the context of searching for something...

Comment: see also sowered/soured

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like some more explanation on this [*scower* vs *scour*].
> Why is the word 'obsolete' as well as not being more widely used?

The explanation is actually very simple. *Scower* is not an obsolete word; as you point out, it's still used. Rather, it's an obsolete **Spelling**. There's only one verb with those meanings, it's pronounced /skawr/, and it's usually spelled *scour*. But it has also been spelled *scower*, and that's the way you apparently learned to spell it. English spelling is commodious enough to provide several convenient spellings for just about any word, and often does.

Spelling a word differently does not change the word; it's still the same word.
Spelling is orthography, which is technological. Language, by contrast, is natural.

Answer (score 1):

This has caught my attention as well, considering most of my life I have heard scower to mean "to search", and scour to mean the cleaning definition. They even have different pronunciations. After speaking to some linguistics inclined people in my area, I must assume it is regional. Perhaps the area around **New England** has kept this in some way as it faded elsewhere and it has simply not yet been recognized. If you are not from around that region though, I have absolutely no idea.